# Why isn't venv running automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

According to

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

and

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

you shouldn't NEED to explicitly activate a created virtual environment before running your scripts:

"You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. **However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it**, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically."

However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
    ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ mkdir project
    ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ python3.8 -m venv project/venv     
    ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ echo """import delorean
    print(\"Hello\")""" > project/testing.py
    ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ source project/venv/bin/activate   
    (venv) ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ pip3.8 install delorean       
    Collecting delorean
      ...
      Running setup.py install for delorean ... done
    Successfully installed babel-2.8.0 delorean-1.0.0 humanize-2.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 six-1.15.0 tzlocal-2.1
    WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    (venv) ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ python3.8 project/testing.py   
    Hello
    (venv) ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ deactivate
    ➜  Python git:(master) ✗ cd project 
    ➜  project git:(master) ✗ python3.8 testing.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "testing.py", line 1, in <module>
        import delorean
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delorean'
    ➜  project git:(master) ✗
```

When I explicityly activate the virtual environment things work as expected, but when I'm in my project and do not do so, the virtual environment does not seem to modify execution, despite what the documentation implies.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: As far as I know you need to call the _python_ binary from the virtual environment's `bin` directory: `path/to/project/venv/bin/python testing.py`. Similarly you could have installed _delorean_ without activating the environment: `path/to/project/venv/bin/python -m pip install deloran`.

Comment: It means that activation makes it easier to run the right Python executable, by updating your PATH shell variable. If you don’t activate the venv you have to include the path to the executable, so`venv/bin/python` or `venv/bin/pip`, instead of `python` and `pip`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Doc clearly states that

You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; **activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path**, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically.

You have to manually add binary path of venv to your **PATH** variable and export it .

if you check the content of **activate** file you can see its just adding the venv binary location to your path.

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/user2/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the Python binary in the virtual environment's `bin` directory (or `Scripts` on Windows):

```
path/to/project/venv/bin/python testing.py
```

Similarly you could have installed `delorean` without activating the environment:

```
path/to/project/venv/bin/python -m pip install delorean
```

This works with any binary in the `bin` (or `Scripts` on Windows) directory of the virtual environment, so for example with pip:

```
path/to/project/venv/bin/pip install delorean
```

This should work in most cases. Otherwise you might need to do the environment variables modifications that the activation script does by yourself. It should be something like setting `VIRTUALENV` to `/absolute/path/to/venv` and prepending `/absolute/path/to/venv/bin` to `PATH`.